# How to write many files using loop in R from many dataframes?

Tags: r, file, loops

I have 22 different dataframes that I have read from 22 different files and named the objects r1 to r22. Now I want to write them in 22 different files again. I want to use loop. Here is my script:

```
for(i in 1:2)  {        
    write.table(paste("r", i, sep = ""), paste("r",i,".txt",sep="") , sep = " ",
                col.names=F, row.names=FALSE, quote=F)  
}
```

It does not write the value of r1 in file "r1" it actually writes "r1" only in the file and saves it.

Would you please tell me what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `paste("r", i, sep = "")` with `eval(parse(text=paste("r", i, sep = "")))`

So now your code will read:

```
for(i in 1:22) {
write.table(eval(parse(text=paste("r", i, sep = ""))), paste("r",i,".txt",sep="") , 
            sep = " ",col.names=F, row.names=FALSE, quote=F)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it was awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have all 22 data.frames as separate objects in the environment? In that case then the for loop is probably the easiest option.

Just as an alternative method in case you will be doing this kind of thing frequently, when reading the files in I would have collected them into a list, then you can write them out the same way.

```
# assuming there is a file list like this with each element a data.frame
file.list <- list(r1,r2,r3...r22)

file.names <- paste(rep("r", length(file.list)), c(1:length(file.list)), sep = "")

mapply(function(x,y) {write.table(x, y, sep = " ", col.names=F, row.names=FALSE, quote=F)}, file.list, file.names)
```